# summing list in recursion

Tags: java, list, recursion

whats my problem? 
I've tried to sum  list and it always returns 0

```
public static int sum(List<Integer> l, Node<Integer> pos, int sum)  
{  
    if(pos==null)  
        return 0;  
    sum=sum+pos.getInfo();  
    pos=pos.getNext();  
    return sum+sum(l, pos, sum);  
}

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int sum=0; 
    List<Integer> l = new List<Integer>(); 
    Node<Integer> pos = l.getFirst(); 

    l = input(l, pos); 
    System.out.println(l); 
    System.out.println(sum(l, pos, sum)); 
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Is the `pos` you are passing `null`?

Comment: but the sum is already made so why this is relevant?

Comment: show your function call.

Comment: What's the point of passing `l` around if you aren't using it?

Comment: You appear to be trying to sum the elements in l, but you never do anything with l.

Comment: It is relevant because your first iteration will return 0 since `pos == null == true`

Comment: im using it: pos=l.getFirst();

Comment: You haven't populated your list.

Comment: You're not using it the sum method.

Comment: and your first is null.

Comment: What kind of list it is? `java.util.List` does not have a method `getFirst()`. I think you should post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2):

You say in the comments that your call site is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0;
    List<Integer> l = new List<Integer>();
    Node<Integer> pos = l.getFirst();      //<======= `pos' refers to the empty list
    l = input(l, pos);
    System.out.println(l);
    System.out.println(sum(l, pos, sum));
}
```

The problem is that, since you initialize `pos` before you add anything to the list, you always sum up the original (empty) list.

Comment: what do you mean? I though that when pos=l.getFirst(); it always points to a memory, and after the input this memory is occupied so pos!=null anymore

Comment: @pleasedeleteme.: Run your program in a debugger and examine `pos`.

Comment: @pleasedeleteme. there is no getFirst() in list API . check here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: In my school API there is. I'm sorry please explain me the problem why pos!=null anymore (the memory which pos points to is not null after the input)

Comment: but the getFirst() of a LinkedList<Integer> does not returns a Node :)

Comment: Its not a Linked list constructor.

Comment: @pleasedeleteme. : Variables in Java do not "point to a memory", they contains values. If the value assigned to `pos` is null, it will always be null until you assign it something else.

Comment: no, pos is an object so what you say is not true. Object doesn't have a value it points to a memory.

Comment: `pos` is a variable which may holds onto a reference to an object, an integral value (int, char, etc) or the null pointer. Even if it holds a reference to an object, it will always hold this reference unless assigned something else.

Comment: That said, we can not be sure what is pos here because it depends on the implementation of your school API. So we can not help you until we know the specifications of your school API.